# Can you provide more feedback for the power editors?

Tags: feature-request, badges, edits, badge-request

I'm asking that we create some more badges to reflect the contribution that "power editors" make to the site.  Currently we have only the one badge (which is non-repeatable), "Strunk & White".

[image]

Suggestions:

- Make the silver, "Strunk & White", badge repeatable.
- Create a gold badge for a significant number of edits
- Expose the number of edits a user has made on their profile somewhere.

I'm a very "pro-edit" user and I strongly believe it is a behavior that should be encouraged.  The biggest contribution I make to the site is cleaning up peoples posts where English isn't their first language or providing relevant links.

Are there bad edits? Sure.  But there are way, way, way more good edits than bad. After doing a marathon of a post-cleanup session I feel like a user should be able to see and chart their contribution through badges/counts.  If it isn't worth recognizing users who hand edit and re-tag thousands of questions then I don't know who is.

Note: Originally this had a decent number of votes on [Uservoice](http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/114885-give-more-feedback-for-us-hardcore-editors-?lang=cn) and the response was it was waiting on a database refactoring in 4-6 weeks.  Well that was a long time ago, so I'm hoping that we can work towards getting some of this implemented with the new DB design.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea to me too.

Comment: 4-6 weeks?  Not 6-8?  Sounds fishy to me

Comment: +1 Aye, it is a noble cause

Comment: Related: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/

Comment: Image rotted. I can't see it anymore.

Answer (score 9):

I imagine you and **He Who Shall Not Be Named** would be big recipients of this. I am all for a greater number of badges across a variety of scenarios (and offering higher level badges for some things that are already there). If we are going to reward someone for Strunk & White, I don't see why it wouldn't be possible to reward them for even greater community committment, or to continue rewarding them for their ongoing work.

Comment: @TheTXI, Well, "he" *cough* RichB *cough* will blow me out of the water when it comes to edits.  By like 10 fold.

Comment: Simucal: Oh you've done done it now

Comment: If you stare into your monitor and say *his* name three times, he suddenly appears and starts rolling back your edits.

Comment: @gnovice: BOOOOO. Stolen from pesto.

Comment: @Rich: Really? Darn, I thought I was the first one to make that joke.

Answer (score 9):

I've said repeatedly that the editors are every bit as much invested / involved / etc in the site, and that the editing is almost always for the good. If the rep and badges are meant to encourage desirable behaviour, then I'm all for ways to express this.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to fix errors on the ethertubes is like subtracting 1 from infinity, but I'll keep on trying